# meaning of ## in SQL Server Profiler trace data

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I'm running a trace using the SQL Server Profiler.  The trace data contains the following lines:

```
WHERE CAST(LEFT(pc.Time_stamp,11) AS DATETIME >= ##
AND CAST(LEFT(pc.Time_stamp, 11) AS DATETIME) <= ##
```

What does the ## mean

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're using SQL Server 2008 or higher, the Profiler is deprecated - look into using [Extended Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx) instead.

The `##` marks serve as a placeholder for the value of the variables being used in the query.